# How to position selected item at first while category selection with listview

Tags: flutter

I am creating a demo where I have used listview builder to show all available categories from a list, now when I tap on item, it should be placed at the first place....

I have attached an image to make it more clear...

I tried with swiping but looks like not a proper way as it is affecting original list order;

here is my coding

```
class _Stack17State extends State<Stack17> {
  @override
  List<String> names = ['Shoes','Trousers','Jeans','Jacket','Belt','Others'];
  int selectedindex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: names.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: (){
                      setState(() {

// I applied this logic, but looks like not proper way as it is spoiling or original list's order;

                        selectedindex=index;
                        swap(selectedindex); 
                        selected index=0;






                      });
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30,vertical: 10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: selectedindex==index?Colors.blue:Colors.blue.shade100,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                        child: Center(child: Text(names[index])),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10,),
          Center(child: Text('Selected Category :  '+names[selectedindex]),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

void swapitems(int index)
  {
    String temp;
    temp=names[index];
    names[index]=names[0];
    names[0]=temp;
  }


}
```

[image]

Comment: After replacing order should be : Jeans-> Shoes-> Trousers->Jacket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
onTap: () {
    var item = names[index];
    names.removeAt(index);
    names.insert(0, item);
    setState(() {});
},
```

`names[0]=temp;` just replace first Item with selected one. you need to use insert which shift the list and insert the selected item to the first place.

Comment: I applied the similar logic..but what if I don't want to affect original list...doe it mean I have to copy to an extra list?

Comment: yes you need an extra list like displayList and do all your update on that and show that list in listview.

Comment: don't forget to pass your original list to displayList by value not by reference. like this` List displayList = [...names]`

Comment: Yes. I felt an issue and solved it by passing as a value not reference